# Calling a Servlet when loading the index page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I need to load a list of some data from a database and show them on my index JSP page. My way of doing that is call a Servlet in the index page like this.

```xml
<body>
    <jsp:include page="listAll" />
    <fieldset>

        <legend>Search Here</legend>
        <input type="text" id="search" name="search"/>
        <input type="button" value="Search" id="searchBtn"/>

    </fieldset>

</body>
```

I am going to do my coding in listAll servlet and add an attribute to the request. What I need to know is, Is this way correct? Can I do what I need like that?
If not, How to do that?

Comment: if you wanted to use servlet use it with ajax it will do exactly what you wanted .as you can't include a servlet in jsp:include.it is only posible if you have response type set there

Answer (score 3):

In a Java Web App, there is an attribute of the web.xml file called the `welcome-file-list`.

The `welcome-file-list` tells the web app what URLs to pull up if nothing more specific is specified.

Typically, this value is configured for `index.jsp`, but it can be any mapping within the web application.

If you wanted to have a servlet respond, instead of `index.jsp`, then you would map the servlet properly, and then use that reference in the `welcome-file-list`.

Consider:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>IndexServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pkg.IndexServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>IndexServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here we have the `pkg.IndexServlet` mapped to `/index`. We also tell the application that `index` is the welcome file for this application. So, internally, when the application sees `http://host.com/webapp`, it will automatically append `index` to it, and then route that appropriately, which will lead it to the servlet mapped to `/index`.

Once you have this mapped properly, you want to do a pattern much @Matthias did here, where the servlet gathers the data, and then forwards to the JSP.

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure if I understood what you are trying to do. But I believe that you try show a list of data in a JSP page and you want to implement a Servlet that does the actual heavy-lifting of getting everything from the DB and things like this.

If I were you I would do it this way: Create a servlet, that performs the actual calls against the database and loads your data into a request attribute. Then you forward from the Servlet to a JSP that actually displays the data

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws ServletException {
    List<DataElement> list = new ArrayList<DataElement>(); // lets assume this is the list we got from the DB
    request.setAttribute("list", list); 
    String nextJSP = "/searchResults.jsp";
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
    dispatcher.forward(request,response);
}
```

In the JSP you can then access the request attributes and iterate them with JSTL

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<body>
<c:forEach var="dataElem" items="${list}">
   Item <c:out value="${dataElem.someValue}"/><p>
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You showed the `doPost` method, but for an `index` page I think that `doGet` is more approriate ...

Comment: Serge sure for an index page the get Method would be better, will edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks ok. you can wrap this things in the `form`. so that you get them in the servlet.

```
<form action="servletURL" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="search" name="search"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" id="searchBtn"/>
</form>
```

you can get those values using [`request#getParameter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) in your `doPost()` method.