# Root "/" mades server load index.html before pass through the servlet

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, web.xml, welcome-file

I have a Servlet that is mapped to the root directory "/":

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Main</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.motorola.triage.MainServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Main</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In this servet there is a couple of small things that are done there, like authentication and retrieve of Google Plus information. After that, I'm doing a forward to a JSP file called "index.jsp"

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(req,resp);
```

When I'm accessing "localhost:8080/" the static file "index.jsp" is loaded without passing through the servlet. For architecture reasons I can not change the name of index.jsp. I would like to ask if is there any way to change this behavior of the server and make it look to the servlet before look the index.jsp file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How load servlet on index.jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839854/how-load-servlet-on-index-jsp)

Comment: @Alex it is not duplicated once he wants to call a SERVLET after the JSP is loaded. I just want to access a servlet endpoint when accessing "/", without passing through the JSP.

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring specifically because you used the name `index.jsp`.

This has been covered elsewhere, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15839904/291796) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26318978/291796) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10414619/291796).

Comment: So there is no way to change this behavior with any server deployment config?

Comment: Thanks, Alex. Those solutions works like a charm when running with appengineRun, locally. But when deployed it seems like the GAE is ignoring my welcome-file. :(